# Combine`s subscribe(on:options:) operator

Tags: swift, combine, frp

I have a question about the [subscribe(on:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/subscribe(on:options:)) operator. I would appreciate if anyone can help me to figure it out.

So what we have from the documentation:

> Specifies the scheduler on which to perform subscribe, cancel, and request operations.
> In contrast with receive(on:options:), which affects downstream messages, subscribe(on:options:) changes the execution context of upstream messages.

Also, what I got from different articles is that unless we explicitly specify the `Scheduler` to receive our downstream messages on (using `receive(on:options:)`), messages will be send on the `Scheduler` used for receiving a subscription.

This information is not aligned with what I am actually getting during the execution.

I have the next code:

```
Just("Some text")
    .map { _ in
        print("Map: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .sink { _ in
        print("Sink: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

I would expect next output:

```
Map: false
Sink: false
```

But instead I am getting:

```
Map: true
Sink: false
```

The same thing happens when I use `Sequence` publisher.

If I swap the position of `map` operator and `subscribe` operator, I receive what I want:

```
Just("Some text")
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .map { _ in
        print("Map: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
    .sink { _ in
        print("Sink: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Output:

```
Map: false
Sink: false
```

Interesting fact is that when I use the same order of operators from my first listing with my custom publisher, I receive the behaviour I want:

```
struct TestJust<Output>: Publisher {
    typealias Failure = Never
    
    private let value: Output
    
    init(_ output: Output) {
        self.value = output
    }
    
    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        subscriber.receive(subscription: Subscriptions.empty)
        _ = subscriber.receive(value)
        subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
    }
}

TestJust("Some text")
    .map { _ in
        print("Map: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .sink { _ in
        print("Sink: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Output:

```
Map: false
Sink: false
```

So I think there is either my total misunderstanding of all these mechanisms, or some publishers intentionally choose the thread to publish values (`Just`, `Sequence` -> `Main`, `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` -> `Some of Background`), which does not make sense for me, cause in this case why would we need this `subscribe(on:options:)` for.

Could you please help me to understand what am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that messages flow both *up* a pipeline and *down* a pipeline. Messages that flow *up* a pipeline ("upstream") are:

- The actual performance of the subscription (receive subscription)
- Requests from a subscriber to the upstream publisher asking for a new value
- Cancel messages (these percolate upwards from the final subscriber)

Messages that flow *down* a pipeline ("downstream") are:

- Values
- Completions, consisting of either a failure (error) or completion-in-good-order (reporting that the publisher emitted its last value)

Okay, well, as the documentation clearly states, `subscribe(on:)` is about the former: *messages that flow upstream*. But you are not actually tracking *any* of *those* messages in your tests, so none of your results reflect any information about them! Insert an appropriate `handleEvents` operator above the subscription point to see stuff flow upwards up the pipeline (e.g. implement its `receiveRequest:` parameter):

```
Just("Some text")
    .handleEvents(receiveRequest: {
        _ in print("Handle1: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    })
    .map // etc.
```

Meanwhile, you should make *no* assumptions about the thread on which messages will flow *downstream* (i.e. values and completions). You say:

> Also, what I got from different articles is that unless we explicitly specify the Scheduler to receive our downstream messages on (using `receive(on:options:)`), messages will be send on the Scheduler used for receiving a subscription.

But that seems like a bogus assumption. And nothing about your code determines the downstream-sending thread in a clear way. As you rightly say, you *can* take control of this with `receive(on:)`, but if you don't, I would say you must *assume nothing* about the matter. Some publishers certainly do produce a value on a background thread, such as the data task publisher, which makes perfect sense (the same thing happens with a data task completion handler). Others don't.

What you *can* assume is that operators other than `receive(on:)` will not generally alter the value-passing thread. But whether and how an operator will use the subscription thread to determine the receive thread, that is something you should assume nothing about. To take control of the receive thread, take control of it! Call `receive(on:)` or assume nothing.

Just to give an example, if you change your opening to

```
Just("Some text")
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
```

then both your `map` and your `sink` will report that they are receiving values on the main thread. Why? Because you took control of the receive thread. This works regardless of what you may say in any `subscribe(on:)` commands. They are different matters entirely.

Maybe if you call `subscribe(on:)` but you don't call `receive(on:)`, some things about the downstream-sending thread are determined by the `subscribe(on:)` thread, but I sure wouldn't rely on there being any hard and fast rules about it; there's nothing saying that in the documentation! Instead, don't do that. If you implement `subscribe(on:)`, implement `receive(on:)` too so that *you* are in charge of what happens.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! My main misconception was in understanding what actually this "upstream" flow was. I was thinking upstream is every operator placed before (or above) the ```subscribe(on:)```.

Comment: I'll rewrite my answer to start with that misconception then!

Comment: I hope my rewrite is useful. I'd like to compliment you on a well-asked question: very nice examples. You did your homework before formulating the question.

Comment: Thanks. So `.map` is not a upstream operator. Could it be a downstream operator? Since it transforms values in its closure. Which means it relay on `receive(on:)` to control its thread.